# How to move a file between folders in google Drive API?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

In Javascript.
Since we don't have a specific update method to deal with movement of files and folders in Drive Rest V2, i would need to update the 'parentId' body-argument that i pass via 'resource' parameter in the request ?

[image: Image here]

Comment: Have you tried it?  Also please remember to upload your code not images of your code anyone who would want to test this would have to type it first.

Comment: I tested it. And it was that ideia. For move the file for another folder it's just set another parentId.  Code with corrections:                                                                                                                      
                                gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() 
    { 
       var body = {'parents':[{"id":newParentId }]};
       var request = gapi.client.drive.files.patch({
      'fileId': filId,
      'resource': body
       });

Comment: And what happens? do you get an error?

Comment: I was having a problem before and the function was running without doing anything, i thought the problem was the logic itself. But no, the logic is that, the  JSON syntax of the 'body' argument was wrong. Now with this code above on the comment, is working perfectly, and the file is being moved to the destination folder.  ;)